# Question on Ethereum ERC standard ERC1400

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

According to definition of ERC1400 here
https://github.com/ethereum/eips/issues/1411

it has the ERC-1643: Document Management Standard.

now my question is, How do these documents/files stored?
are they stored in the contract as a hash?
are they uploaded somewhere, if so, where?

Also, while were at it, were can I find sample codes/resources for various ERC standards as well, I dont seem to find any sample codes on theses ERC standards everywhere :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that both standard proposals ([ERC-1400](https://github.com/ethereum/eips/issues/1411) and [ERC-1643](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/1643)) are currently (April 2021) still in the draft phase (for over 2 years since they were created). Meaning they haven't been approved by the core team, and not many developers are going to follow an unapproved standard (or publish code samples).

> *How do these documents/files stored?*

The draft of ERC-1643 **only defines an interface** (function names, argument datatypes, ...), not the actual implementation (how to store the data - that's up to each developer to implement to their use case).

The `string _uri` that the standard defines as one of the arguments, can be:

- IPFS (decentralized storage, my guess is that this is going to be the most common use case)
- off-chain file sharing service such as Google Drive
- or it can even be an URL accessible only on some private networks
- basically any valid URI (so even `ftp://`, `skype://` or `tel://` link)